# why python process only has one thread

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I executed one python grogram and issued the following command "ps -mH -p 10934"(the number was that process Id), I just found one thread in the process. But for a Java process it would start more than 20 threads, such as: gc daemon, management daemon...
Why python process only one thread? how does python do the garbage collection?

Comment: Because they are different runtimes and are implemented differently .. CPython revolves around a single-thread 'kernel' and GIL; *and* it uses reference-counting (with cycle-detection) that results in the ability to immediately handle the GC operations. (For a counter example, about this not being intrinsically part of the language, consider IronPython or Jython projects.)